# Why doesn't this templated function to zero-initialize an array compile?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a simple templated function that will initialize all members of an array to zero (or to their default-constructed state, if the array is an array of objects).  Here's what I've got written:

```
template<typename T, int size> inline void ClearTheArray(T[size] theArray) 
{
   for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++) theArray[i] = T();
}
```

... the idea being that I could then reset any array to its default-constructed/all-zeroes state like this:

```
int myArray[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
ClearTheArray(myArray);
// myArray now contains all zeroes

int * somePointer = myArray;
ClearTheArray(somePointer);  // compile error: somePointer doesn't contain array length info
```

However, the above doesn't compile; instead I get a syntax error ("expected ')'") at the first instance of `theArray` in the formal arguments list.  What am I doing wrong here?  Is there a way to do this right?

Comment: Does `T[size] theArray` actually work?

Comment: Not for me it doesn't... OTOH this function *does* work, so go figure:  template<typename T, int size> inline bool IsArrayIndexIsValid(int i, T(&)[size] /*theArray*/) {return (((unsigned int)i) < size);}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `T[size] theArray` is simply not correct declaration syntax. Just like when declaring arrays in any other context, the name goes before the bounds. So `T theArray[size]` would be the right syntax.

But this will still not do what you want it to do because arrays can't be passed by value and trying to pass an array by value causes it to decay to a pointer. The compiler must rewrite your parameter declaration to simply `T* theArray`. This makes `size` impossible to deduce, and allows your function to accept arbitrary pointers.

To solve these issues, you have to pass the array *by reference:*

```
template<typename T, int size> inline void ClearTheArray(T (&theArray)[size]) 
{
   for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++) theArray[i] = T();
}
```

Then your example usage will behave as you expect.

There's no sense re-inventing the wheel though. The standard way to do this is

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;
std::fill(begin(myArray), end(myArray), 0);
std::fill(begin(somePointer), end(somePointer), 0);  // compile error
```